# React re-render does not work. img src does not load

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, rerender

the code below is supposed to download 5 urls from firebase and when it is already downloaded, it passes 1 url to "currentUrl" state. after that url should be passed to `<img url.../>` below and img should load. the problem is, img does not load... . and I am 100% sure that "currentUrl" actually contains proper url afer a few milliseconds.

custom useFirestore hook uses useEffect in order to fetch the 5 urls.

SLIDER.JS

```
import "./Slider.css"
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useFirestore} from "../../../hooks/useFirestore";
 
 
const Slider = () => {
 
    const [currentUrl, setCurrentUrl] = useState("")
 
 
//////in useFirestore hook, use effect downloads 5 urls from firebase and pass them to 
/////// photoUrls state
 
      const {sliderUrls:photoUrls} = useFirestore()
 
    useEffect(()=>{
        if (photoUrls){
            setCurrentUrl(photoUrls[0])
 
    },[photoUrls, currentUrl])
 
    return (
        <div className="slider">
            <img className="slider-img" src={currentUrl} alt="photo"/>
        </div>
    );
 
};
 
export default Slider;
```

USEFIRESTORE.JS

```
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {storage} from "../firebase/config"
import {ref, getDownloadURL} from "firebase/storage";


export const useFirestore = () => {
    const [sliderUrls, setSliderUrls]  = useState(null)


useEffect(()=>{

    const results = [];
    for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
        getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `slider/slider-${i}.png`)).then((url)=>{
            results.push(url)
        })
    }
    setSliderUrls(results)
},[])




    return {sliderUrls};
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have 100% of the time an image i think you are lucky.
For me just looking at the code your result is always empty.

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {storage} from "../firebase/config"
import {ref, getDownloadURL} from "firebase/storage";


export const useFirestore = () => {
    const [sliderUrls, setSliderUrls]  = useState(null)

  const fetchFirestoreImages = useCallback(async () => {
      const promises = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
          const urlPromise = getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `slider/slider-${i}.png`));
          promises.push(urlPromise);
       }
       return Promise.all(promises)
  }, [])


useEffect(()=>{

    fetchFirestoreImages().then(urls => {
      setSliderUrls(urls)
    })
    
},[fetchFirestoreImages])

    return {sliderUrls};
}
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the answer but the issue is somewhere else.

my custom hook downloads urls properly.

if u place console.log(photoUrls) to useEffect in SLIDER.js file under setCurrentUrl(photoUrls[0]) its going to print all the 5 urls. so urls are fetched properly.

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console, or in the network tab on the image url call (dev tools)?

Comment: oh, You were actually right.  App is working fine now with your code. I still don't know what was actually wrong, but previously the hook downloaded urls, pushed them to sliderUrls state and after that reseted sldierUrls state... . Thanks a lot though!

Comment: Your code would have worked if you pushed the state  : 
You have to init the state with an empty array
getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `slider/slider-${i}.png`)).then((url)=>{
            setSliderUrls(urls => [...urls,url]);
        })

But you pushed the empty array before the promises finished